Xamarin Android LifecycleOwner Build Error DevOps Pipeline
I cannot figure out why I am getting the following build error in my DevOps Pipeline when building a Xamarin Android app.  The APK builds find but the AAB build always fails.
[error]Core\BarcodeScanner\Droid\obj\Release\130\android\src\crc643f46942d9dd1fff9\FormsAppCompatActivity.java(4,8): Error JAVAC0000:  error: cannot access LifecycleOwner
public class FormsAppCompatActivity
class file for androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner not found
